# Select query for a table is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, select

here I have 2 selections that I have used for a table I have created but it doesn't seem to be working. the fields are the same as the MySQL table.

can anyone see the issue im having? I have tried both of these?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Triage WHERE 'Traige completed' = 'No'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

or

```
$sql="
  SELECT t2.*
  FROM Triage t2
  WHERE t2.'Traige completed' = 'No'
";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages or is not the expected result ? Have you tried the queries in a mysql console beforehand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error Message ?

Try

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Triage WHERE `Traige completed` = 'No'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

` instead of '

Comment: you were right, I changed `Traige completed` to completed and just entered that in instead but had the same out come and worked :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need use backticks rather than `'`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Triage  WHERE `Traige completed` = 'No'";
```

instead of

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Triage WHERE 'Traige completed' = 'No'";
```

Comment: you were right, I changed `Traige completed` to completed and just entered that in instead but had the same out come and worked :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be spelling "triage" wrong in your WHERE clauses. What happens if you change it to be consistent with the table name?